# Curl, Adding hostname from array

Tags: arrays, bash, curl, url

I am trying to write a script that parses the output of a URL.  Everything works great if I hard code a URL into the curl command, however when I try to add the URL from an array I am getting a syntax error.

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
hosts=(
room-f3185-dsp
room-c5180-dsp
room-f3187-dsp
room-f3183-dsp
)

for i in "${hosts[@]}"
url1=$(curl -d "action=login&userPassword=PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://$i)
url2=$(echo $url | sed 's/,/\n/g')
url3=$(echo $url2 | sed 's/:/ /g' | grep macAddress ./mactest | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}')
url4=$(echo $url3 | sed 's/ /:/g' | tr -d '"')
mac=$(echo $url4 | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.$//' |sed 's/.$//')
echo "------------------------------------------------" >> dspmac
echo $i >> dspmac
echo "Mac Address = "$mac  >> dspmac
done
```

Here is the error I am getting,
line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `url1=$(curl -d "action=login&userPassword=PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST $i)'

Also in the url1 line when I put in HTTP:// it is highlighted as a link, but the $i is just showing as standard text

Thank in advance

If I replace the $i in the script with the full URL (http://room-f3185-dsp) it works great.  I have also tried putting the full url as the host in the array, but still get the same error.
I also tried various quotes in different places.

Comment: consider cutting-n-pasting your script (including shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes; shellcheck should tell you that you've got an invalid `for` loop construct (ie, you're missing the `do`)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `do`:

```
for i in "${hosts[@]}"
do
    ...
done
```